# Problem with dropdown action on Bootstrap v4

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I have this sample page that I can't get the down down to work.

I have loaded jQuery, then Bootstrap, then popper (put popper before breaks things)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap try out</title>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js'></script>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.5/umd/popper.min.js" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="input-group text dropright " >
        <input class="form-control" readonly type="text" placeholder="<category map>">  <!-- form-control links field with the span -->
        <div class="input-group-append" dropdown>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">dd
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This renders the button - but the drop down doesn't open.

What I have missed here ?

PS: corrected page - putting the dropdown inside class "" like this it still doesn't render the list - something else is not right.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="input-group text dropright " >
        <input class="form-control" readonly type="text" placeholder="<category map>">  <!-- form-control links field with the span -->
        <div class="input-group-append dropdown" >
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">dd
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="input-group-append" dropdown>` dropdown should be inside class quotes.

Comment: that was silly - however i fixed that as shown below and it still doesn't render so it must be something else

Comment: `placeholder="<category map>"` - you should replace the placeholder text to `placeholder="&lt;category map&gt;"`.

Comment: `<div class="input-group text dropright " >` remove `dropright` class from here

Comment: i'll tidy that tomorrow and thx for the corrections in style.  However not the answer seemed to be be with the header sources - when i commented those out and replaced with equiv 4 sources on w3c schools site it started to work .  Absolutely no idea whats going on there

Answer (score 0):

really weird - so went to a demo site [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h)  - and there demo worked

so I cust and paste the header from that to my page and commented out my 4 lines doing same stuff

see replacement here - when i commented out my original sources and replaced those with the the same as the  w3c schools and reloaded the page - it works

```
<!--  these 4 lines do work -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<%-- these 4 lines dont work
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
--%>
```

i'm not sure what nature of screwedness is going on and its too late to go figure.  However with the new sources the pages start to work - very weird